# How to fix incomplete data/log

Tags: sql-server

I have a message log table, ordered by date, like this:

```
    Id      Name      Date                Type            Text
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    1       Vasya     2018/05/01 08:00    In              NULL
    2       Vasya     2018/05/01 09:00    Message         Hello
    3       Vasya     2018/05/01 18:00    Out             NULL
    4       Petya     2018/05/02 08:00    In              NULL
----- missing part (with message of type In)
    5       Vasya     2018/05/02 15:00    Message         Hello
    6       Vasya     2018/05/02 18:00    Out             NULL
    7       Petya     2018/05/02 18:10    Message         Good bye
    8       Petya     2018/05/02 19:00    Out             NULL
----- missing part (with message of type In)
    9       Masha     2018/05/03 09:00    Out             NULL
----- missing part (with message of type In)
    10      Ivan      2018/05/03 10:00    Hi              NULL
----- missing part (with message of type Out)
```

They can send such a broken log and I need to fix it by adding corresponding In/Out messages for each user when they are missing.

Looking from bottom to the top:

1. If some user's Out message has no corresponding In message anywhere earlier (by date) in log, I need to add one to the top of the log. 
   Example: N9 Out -> N0 (date) In to the top.

This I could do by finding Out messages which have no In messages anywhere earlier using NOT EXISTS() per user.

2. If there is first Out message and there is also another second Out somewhere earlier, I need to add In messsage after that second Out message 
   Example: N6 Out -> In after N3

This where I stuck, I now realize that I needed to JOIN Out messages to corresponding OUT messages which go earler ...

3. For each message with type NULL add wrapping In/Out (actually Outs can be skipped)

Thanks,

Slava

Comment: Looks like I am comming to that :) I need something like: select Type from log as l outer apply (select top 1 Type, Date from log where Date < l.Data and Type is null or Type = Out order by Date desc) ... will be trying

Answer (score 0):

To find missing Ins for Outs, something like this:

```
;with Ins (Id, Name, Date, Type, Text)
as
(
select l.Id, l.Name, plm.Date, plm.Type, l.Text
from Log as l
   outer apply (select top 1 pl.Date, pl.Type
                from Log as pl 
                where pl.Type in ('In', 'Out') 
                      and pl.User = l.User
                      and pl.Date < l.Date
                order by pl.Date desc) as plm
where l.Type = 'Out'
)
insert into Log (Id, Name, Date, Type, Text)
select Id + 1, Name, 
     case 
       when Date is null 
       then '2000/01/01'
       else dateadd(second, -1, Date) -- make In a second earlier then Out
     end as NewDate,
     'In',
     Text
from Ins
where Type <> 'In'
```

It looks like it is similar to find missing Ins for just messages